# Using SimpleForm with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Rails application that uses the SimpleForm gem. The current SimpleForm 3.0.0.rc version provides attractive form styling using Bootstrap 2.3. But when I use Bootstrap 3.0, I lose the nice form styling. How do I use SimpleForm with Bootstrap 3?

Comment: You can try the [RailsLayout Gem](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_layout).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integration of simple\_form with bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935536/integration-of-simple-form-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/857 - this can be helpful.

You need to change simple form initializer. [Here](https://gist.github.com/tokenvolt/6599141) is what I used in one of my projects

**UPD Apr 22, 2014**

[Simple Form 3.1.0.rc1 with support to Bootstrap 3](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/04/bootstrap-3-support-for-simple-form).

Comment: I use simple_form 2.1, is there a way to make it works only with the custom initializer? I guess that not since they probably added some features in the gem, that are not available in `< 3.x`.

Comment: @tokenvolt - thanks a bunch!  I just included the code from you link and the fields in my form worked like magic!

Comment: The initializer linked to breaks Active Admin, I have included my improvement as a comment to the original gist.

Answer (score 8):

This gist:

https://gist.github.com/tokenvolt/6599141

Was very helpful to me!

EDIT - Pasted the current contents of the gist into SO because of moderator comments not liking link-only responses. However, it's probably best to pull it from the gist.

Big thanks to @Tokenvolt

```
inputs = %w[
  CollectionSelectInput
  DateTimeInput
  FileInput
  GroupedCollectionSelectInput
  NumericInput
  PasswordInput
  RangeInput
  StringInput
  TextInput
]

inputs.each do |input_type|
  superclass = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{input_type}".constantize

  new_class = Class.new(superclass) do
    def input_html_classes
      super.push('form-control')
    end
  end

  Object.const_set(input_type, new_class)
end

# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.boolean_style = :nested

  config.wrappers :bootstrap3, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error',
      defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } } do |b|

    b.use :html5
    b.use :min_max
    b.use :maxlength
    b.use :placeholder

    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :readonly

    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
  end

  config.wrappers :prepend, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group' do |prepend|
    prepend.use :label , class: 'input-group-addon' ###Please note setting class here fro the label does not currently work (let me know if you know a workaround as this is the final hurdle)
        prepend.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :append, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-group' do |prepend|
        prepend.use :input
    prepend.use :label , class: 'input-group-addon' ###Please note setting class here fro the label does not currently work (let me know if you know a workaround as this is the final hurdle)
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block has-error' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :checkbox, tag: :div, class: "checkbox", error_class: "has-error" do |b|

    # Form extensions
    b.use :html5

    # Form components
    b.wrapper tag: :label do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :label_text
    end

    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
  end

  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap3
end
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This breaks Active Admin, I have included my improvement as a comment to the original Gist.

Answer (score 1):

Add an initializer to your project for simple form  ( `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` ) and drop in the contents of this gist:

https://gist.github.com/tommarshall/6308327/0141a600a93a1711d4762a04dd0d85a3ee14041e

I just went through this and that gist worked around bootstraps new layout / classnames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bootstrap specific simple_form setting by creating a config/initializers/simple_form.rb with this content:

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-lg-6' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  # div class="form-group"
  #   label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1" Text Field

  #   div class="col-sm-9"
  #     input type="text" id="form-field-1" placeholder="Username" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5"
  # div class="space-4"

  config.wrappers :prepend, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-lg-6' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-prepend' do |prepend|
        prepend.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :append, tag: 'div', class: "form-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'col-lg-6' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-append' do |append|
        append.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
end
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 replaced control-group with form-group as well as other changes so older initializers no longer work. See the new example here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-example

Comment: @genkilabs Oh. yes right form-group sorry. I will make a correction.

Answer (score 0):

Active Admin may actually raise an error like this:

```
ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (6 for 4..5):
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc3) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:241:in `input'
  enumerize (0.8.0) lib/enumerize/hooks/formtastic.rb:23:in `input_with_enumerize'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:26:in `block in input'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:150:in `with_new_form_buffer'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:26:in `input'
  app/admin/comment.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:142:in `block in field_set_and_list_wrapping'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:52:in `capture_with_haml'
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc3) lib/formtastic/helpers/fieldset_wrapper.rb:32:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:141:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
  formtastic (2.3.0.rc3) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:297:in `inputs'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `block in inputs'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:150:in `with_new_form_buffer'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `inputs'
  app/admin/comment.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:23:in `block in main_content'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:52:in `capture_with_haml'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:139:in `form_for_with_haml'
  haml (4.0.5) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:28:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formtastic-2.3.0.rc3/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:174:in `block in semantic_form_for'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formtastic-2.3.0.rc3/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:197:in `with_custom_field_error_proc'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/formtastic-2.3.0.rc3/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:173:in `semantic_form_for'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/form_helper.rb:9:in `active_admin_form_for'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:175:in `method_missing'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:22:in `main_content'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:82:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:81:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:65:in `block in build_page_content'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:64:in `build_page_content'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:44:in `block in build_page'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:43:in `build_page'
   () usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb:1:in `block in __usr_local__ellar_rbenv_______versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_active_admin_ad__a_f_c____app_views_active_admin_resource_edit_html_arb___673488922967484373_70297770858860'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/app/views/active_admin/resource/edit.html.arb:1:in `__usr_local__ellar_rbenv_______versions_______lib_ruby_gems_______bundler_gems_active_admin_ad__a_f_c____app_views_active_admin_resource_edit_html_arb___673488922967484373_70297770858860'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:238:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:165:in `to_html'
  responders (1.0.0) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:104:in `to_html'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:158:in `respond'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:151:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:400:in `respond_with'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:25:in `edit'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  dragonfly (1.0.4) lib/dragonfly/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  dragonfly (1.0.4) lib/dragonfly/cookie_monster.rb:9:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.16) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

If you are having this problem, you can instead use this in your initializer:

```
inputs = %w[
  CollectionSelectInput
  DateTimeInput
  FileInput
  GroupedCollectionSelectInput
  NumericInput
  PasswordInput
  RangeInput
  StringInput
  TextInput
]

inputs.each do |input_type|
  "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{input_type}".constantize.class_eval do
    alias_method :__input_html_classes, :input_html_classes
    define_method(:input_html_classes) do
      __input_html_classes.push('form-control')
    end
  end
end
```