# Integration of simple_form with bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've updated bootstrap to version 3. Everything works fine except the forms which are generated by simple_form gem. I don't know how could I integrate these two together. I can't find any helpful suggestion in the github project repository either. So does anyone have a solution for me ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a blog post here http://stabco.tumblr.com/post/59760641051/simple-form-bootstrap3-integration that looks like a good solution. It updates the initializer to suit bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 11):

This gist was very helpful to me:

https://gist.github.com/tokenvolt/6599141

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simple form 3.1.0.rc1 has just been released that should solve your integration problems.
See the blog post about it on http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/04/bootstrap-3-support-for-simple-form/, or just see the latest Simple Form for Bootstrap here: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/.

So if you update your simple form to this version, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a bootstrap specific simple_form setting by creating an initializer in config/initializers and populating with the below content.

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: 'div', class: 'control-group', error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :prepend, tag: 'div', class: "control-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-prepend' do |prepend|
        prepend.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  config.wrappers :append, tag: 'div', class: "control-group", error_class: 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |input|
      input.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'input-append' do |append|
        append.use :input
      end
      input.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
      input.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    end
  end

  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news everyone: as of April 2014, [Bootstrap 3 integration is more fully supported](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/04/bootstrap-3-support-for-simple-form), with extra wrappers provided in a new release.

> We just released Simple Form 3.1.0.rc1 with support to Bootstrap 3.
>   To make it possible, we leveled up the Wrapper API to make it more extensible 
>   and to allow  developers to directly configure it instead of relying on global state. 
>   After such improvements, it was very easy to change the Simple Form configuration to 
>   work with Bootstrap 3.

You can see the new functionality in action through an example app here: http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/